# Is it possible to dump pure HTML dom with Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Usually HTML pages contain scripts and styles and may also reference them in separate files. How can I dump the pure HTML into a static html file with scripts removed and styles merged into html? So that I can view the page with a static html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension from the crhome webstore called [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en).

Comment: thanks! unfortunately SingleFile doesn't work well on the page I want to save. It shows ERR on the processing icon after a while.

Comment: What site are you trying to save

Comment: it's from an interval site within my company. the page contains quite many javascripts. but from user's point of view, the page looks like a static page.